# Outlook addin does not load a server added custom property

Tags: outlook-addin, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

Our Outlook addin saves and loads custom properties. Our server code may also add a property to the list of the addin's custom properties via EWS and OWA and Windows Outlook see those server added properties just fine but for some reason in Outlook for Mac a server added custom property is not available.

Ideas? Is it a bug or some kind of a restriction?

Seems like a Mac Outlook bug because OWA and Windows versions work just fine.

As of 16.14.1 this is still an issue. When will this be fixed?

Comment: (added an outlook-for-mac tag, so they can respond). However, I want to note that changing custom properties via the server, and via the client, can be dangerous. If the client has loaded the item, and then you change custom properties on the server...then the client changes custom properties. Then the last writer will win when the item syncs and the conflicts are resolved.

Comment: Understood. In our case an additional property is added by the server side and it's never updated by the client. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Mac Outlook. We are working towards fixing it.

Comment: Any updates on this? The latest Mac Outlook is still having this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Fix for appointments customproperties issue got checked in. Please use any build version on or after 180805

Comment: Hi, I've just run into a similar problem on build 181015. We're not adding customproperties from the server side, yet if the custom property is added by any other client (e.g. OWA) then Outlook for Mac will not pick it up. Is this the same issue, or should I open a separate question?

Comment: Yep, the issue is not fixed yet. Experiencing it with the build 190220!